# fosUserBundle sends email registration empty

Tags: email, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

so when i registre via fosUserBundle form on production env it sends an email to my gmail but there is no confirmation link in the email, there is just this

```
registration.email.message
```

in the title and in the body of the email, someone knows why ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the email is content obtained using translator and you have wrong configuration.

Make sure you have the translator enabled:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallback: %locale% }

# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    locale: en # default locale
```

Also if you write your app in different language than english, make sure the key `registration.email.message` is translated into it. If it's not, you can override the translations by writing following file:

```
# app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations/FOSUserBundle.{your_locale}.yml
registration:
    email:
        subject: Registration email subject
        message: |
            Here you can place the content of the email.
            It can be multiline and you even have access to
            variables %username% and %confirmationUrl%.
```

Comment: if it still not showing up. try to clear cache. it work for me after

    php app/console cache:clear

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the FOSUser default mail:

```
{% block subject %}
{% autoescape false %}
{{ 'registration.email.subject'|trans({'%username%': user.username, '%confirmationUrl%': confirmationUrl}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body_text %}
{% autoescape false %}
{{ 'registration.email.message'|trans({'%username%': user.username, '%confirmationUrl%': confirmationUrl}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body_html %}{% endblock %}
```

At line 8, 'registration.email.message' is the email content. And `trans` is a replace filter. Try something like this:

```
    {% block subject %}
    {% autoescape false %}
    {{ 'Confirmez votre inscription sur blabla.com'|trans({'%username%': user.username, '%confirmationUrl%': confirmationUrl}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
    {% endautoescape %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block body_text %}
    {% autoescape false %}
    {{ 'Bonjour %username%

    Merci de cliquer sur le lien suivant afin de confirmer votre inscription sur blabla.com:

    %confirmationUrl%'|trans({'%username%': user.username, '%confirmationUrl%': confirmationUrl}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}

{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body_html %}{% endblock %}
```